# github actions: run multiple jobs in the same docker

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I'm learning to deploy github actions to run multiple jobs with docker, and this is what I have so far:

github actions yml file is shown as follow. There are 2 jobs: `job0` builds docker with `Dockerfile0` and `job1` builds docker with `Dockerfile1`.

```
# .github/workflows/main.yml
name: docker CI

on: push

jobs:
  job0:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build and Run
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile0 --tag job0

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build and Run
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile1 --tag job1
```

`Dockerfile0` and `Dockerfile1` share basically the same content, except for the argument in the last line:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ADD . /docker_ci
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y ... ...

WORKDIR /docker_ci
RUN python3 script.py <arg>
```

I wonder, can I build a docker for the 1st job, and then invoke multiple jobs execute command within the docker built from the 1st job? Thus I don't have to keep multiple Dockerfile and save some docker building time.

It would be better to build my docker locally from Dockerfile so I hope to avoid using `container` from docker hub.

[runs-for-docker-actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-docker-actions) looks relevant but I have trouble finding example deploying action locally (without publishing).

Comment: You can create your own Github container actions and with optional input. Essentially you would need an action.yml, a Dockerfile (you already have that). You can run it with `uses: ./` or something like that and with `with` specifications for your argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely sounds like you should **not** build two different images - not for CI, and not for local development purposes (if it matters).

From the details you have provided, I would consider the following approach:

1. Define a Dockerfile with an `ENTRYPOINT` which is the lowest common denominator for your needs (it can be `bash` or `python script.py`).
2. In GitHub Actions, have a single job with multiple steps - one for building the image, and the others for running it with arguments.

For example:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3

WORKDIR /app
COPY script.py .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "script.py"]
```

This `Dockerfile` can be executed with any argument which will be passed on to the `script.py` entrypoint:

```
$ docker run --rm -it imagename some arguments
```

A sample GitHub Actions config might look like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  jobname:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build the image
      run: docker build --tag job .
    - name: Test 1
      run: docker run --rm -it job arg1
    - name: Test 2
      run: docker run --rm -it job arg2
```

If you insist on separating these to different jobs, as far as I understand it, your easiest option would still be to rebuild the image (but still using a single `Dockerfile`), since sharing a docker image built in one job, to another job, will be a more complicated task that I would recommend trying to avoid.